# How would i replace spaces in a string with “%20", recursively?

Tags: haskell

So I've figured this out non-recursively like this:

```
noSpaces :: [Char] -> [Char]    
noSpaces xs = [f | r <- xs, f <- if (r == ' ') then "%20" else [r]]
```

but now i need to figure out how to do that recursively, with no pattern matching and no concatenation...

I figured out other recursive functions (gcd, fib, and a couple others involving numbers) easily enough... but am lost on this for some reason and getting lost-er the more stuff i try that doesn't work...

I found the other answer on here about doing this in Haskell... but that idea uses two separate functions, one being like a helper function -- how would you go about this all in one function, as concisely as possible?

something like:

```
replace [Char] = [Char]
replace (x:xs)
    | x == ' ' = "%20":replace xs
```

which compiles but of course i get the 'non-exhaustive patterns in function' error message, and can't figure out what to put in the 'otherwise' clause...

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If `x` is a space, it should become `"%20"`. You have that part mostly right (`:` should be `++`). If it’s not a space, it should become what, considering what you have available in the function?

Comment: I imagine you have to do it recursively as an exercise for class. Just for your edification, the way you have done it with a list comprehension is quite nice; a recursive implementation of this function would be awkward "in the wild".

Comment: Thank you luqui, I do appreciate that.  And yes, this is for a class -- but not for the actual graded assignment, just the "working through the tutorial" part.  I just hate leaving something un-figured-out, when it's implied there is, indeed, a solution.

Thank you Ry for making me think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the case where it is not a `' '`.
So, try this:

```
replace [] = []
replace (x:xs) 
    | x == ' ' = "%20" ++ replace xs
    | otherwise = x : replace xs
```

You need to use `++` in your first guard because a *string* is a list of chars.

Comment: `... | x==' ' = '%':'2':'0':replace xs` also works, avoiding `++`, but it's less readable

Comment: @chi yeah, you’re right! I think they will understand the idea this way.

Comment: I do like the "more readable" especially when I'm just learning the language... I've only been at this for a week now.  Thank you.

Comment: @Stormy you're welcome! Hope this solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
replace []     = []
replace (x:xs) = (if x == ' ' then "%20" else [x]) ++ replace xs
```